# ajax to coldfusion query stalls

Tags: ajax, coldfusion

I have an ajax call in cfm page to update mysql db, the data will be inserted into the database and then stalls with no error. If I remove insert query page, it returns success.

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: url,
    data: dataString,
    crossDomain: true,
    cache: false,
    beforeSend: function(){ 
       $("#addEvent").html('Connecting...');
    },
    success: function(data){
       if (data=="success") {
          window.location.href = "events.html";
       } else if(data=="failed") {
          navigator.notification.alert('Failed to add event.');
          $("#addEvent").html('addEvent');
       }
    }
});
```

**ColdFusion**

```
<cfif formType eq "addEvent">
    <cfquery name="addEventQuery" datasource="#mysql_db#"   username="#mysql_username#" password="#mysql_password#">
       INSERT INTO events (event_admin) VALUES ('1')
    </cfquery>

    <cfoutput>success</cfoutput>
</cfif>
```

Comment: what means "stalls"? Did you press F12 in the browser and look into console output or return of the network tab?

Comment: Do one thing at a time.  Start by trying the query directly against the database.

Comment: running cfm page directly displays "success"... nothing displayed in console

Comment: stalls: does not return from cfm page to success function, however, db is updated... nothing in console

Comment: I would pay attention more to the format of dataString you are sending and returning from the cfm file.  See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/.